# single array value in multiple array

Tags: php

I am trying a single array value in multiple array . after echo this 
`$users['ride_from']`. I am getting this result `32.9697, -96.80322`. My query is here may i convert this like $point1 who hold the two array. any help.

```
foreach ($usersInfo as $key=> $users){
    $ridefrom = $users['ride_from'];
    $rideto = $users['ride_to'];//this is from lat long
    $point1 = array("lat" => "48.8666667", "long" => "2.3333333"); // Paris (France)
}
```

Comment: No idea what you are trying to achieve/ask... :/

Comment: What exactly is your question? Your statement makes no sense at all.

Comment: Dave @can i convert $ridefrom=(32.9697, -96.80322)  value like this array

("lat" => "48.8666667", "long" => "2.3333333"); // Paris (France)

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
$users['ride_to'] = "32.9697, -96.80322";
$users['ride_to'] = explode(",",$users['ride_to']);

$rideto["lat"] = $users['ride_to'][0];
$rideto["long"] = $users['ride_to'][1]; 


echo "<pre>";print_r($rideto);
```

return: 
Array
(
    [lat] => 32.9697
    [long] =>  -96.80322
)

Comment: Emeeus@this is not returning arryy

Comment: @newdeveloper $rideto is an array in the way I guess you were looking for.

Comment: Emeeus@your gmail id

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$finalDest = array();
foreach ($usersInfo as $key=> $users)
{
      $ridefrom=$users['ride_from'];
      $rideto=$users['ride_to'];//this is from lat long
      $tempLatLong = explode(',',$users['ride_to']);
      $key = array('lat','long');
      $to = array_combine($key,$tempLatLong); 
      array_push($finalDest,$to);  push destination of each user 
}

print_r($finalDest); // displays all array
```

Comment: prasanna puttaswamy@great

Comment: _will be helpful for other users.._ and for your rep